# Connecting Azure SQL databse to shinyapps.io

Tags: sql, r, azure, shiny, shinyapps

I have been trying to connect SQL database (in Azure) to shinyapp deployed in shinyapps.io, but I could connect to the database from local R console. Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

This is the connection string in Azure SQL DB.

[image]

And this is what I am trying from local R console and the connection was successful.

```
    con <- dbConnect(
      odbc(),
      Driver = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0",
      Server = "xxxx.database.windows.net",
      Database = "hist_data",
      UID = "narendra",
      PWD = "xxx",
      Port = 1433
    )
```

I had also connected the Database to the local SSMS.

When I deploy the app, getting error:

```
nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' : file not found
```

Comment: Change driver to `Driver   = "FreeTDS"`

Comment: Thank you @Pork Chop . I was trying "FreeTDS" with TDS_Version = 7.0 but I was getting error. Removing the TDS_version did the trick.. Thanks

Comment: Please create an answer and accept it so others have a reference

Answer (score 1):

I tried to set Driver = "FreeTDS" along with TDS_Version, but it didn't work. However, when I removed the TDS_Version, the app started working on shinyapps.io.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing "tcp:" from the server name prefix. You also need to adjust the driver name to "SQLServer".

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.